# DataStax Devcenter , Cassandra Connection Fails

Tags: cassandra

I have successfully setup Amazon AMI linux instance in AWS EC2 and also updated the Cassandra database from 2.0.16 to 2.1.7.

Connection using CQLSH (localHost) working fine and i want connect remotely from the Devcenter

for that: i have Changed the few thing in Cassandra.yaml Configuration file

---

> start_native_transport: true
>
> rpc_address:0.0.0.0
>
> rpc_broadcastaddress:0.0.0.0

after that : try to restart the Cassandra service

---

Error:cassandra dead but pid file exists

---

so that i can't able to test the connection for devcenter 1.3.1 and cassendra 2.1.7

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, when you set rpc_address to 0.0.0.0, you must set the broadcast_rpc_address setting to a value other than 0.0.0.0.

It sounds like you are trying to set them both to 0.0.0.0, which isn't valid.

Also I don't find a parameter called "rpc_broadcastaddress" in the documentation, so perhaps you are trying to set broadcast_rpc_address with the wrong name.

For that one the documentation says this:

broadcast_rpc_address - (Default: unset) RPC address to broadcast to drivers and other Cassandra nodes. This cannot be set to 0.0.0.0. If blank, it is set to the value of the rpc_address or rpc_interface. If rpc_address or rpc_interface is set to 0.0.0.0, this property must be set.

So try setting broadcast_rpc_address to something other than 0.0.0.0.